# How long do I need from landing to reaching the train station in Zürich Airport when arriving from London?

Tags: trains, airports, british-airways, train-stations, zurich

I am arriving at the Zürich airport from London, scheduled to arrive at 6:20pm in the evening. I am wondering if anybody has an approximate idea of how long it normally takes to get to the train station in the airport once one has landed when coming from England with checked luggage. Depending on the time it takes I would have to decide between two options to get to my final destination:
1. a long distance train leaving around 9pm.
2. take a train from the airport to the central station at around 8pm, to catch a bus at central station at around 8:45pm (I read that the trains from the airport run about every 10 minutes and take 10 to 15 minutes to arrive at central station. Is that correct?)

The advantage of option 2 is that I would arrive 45 minutes earlier at my final destination, which doesn't sound like a lot when it's in then middle of the day, but when it's close to midnight it makes a bit of a difference for me. It would also be slightly cheaper.

I am wondering whether it may take me much longer to walk to the train station than another person that asked a similar question on here, because I'll arrive from London and not from Berlin?
Furthermore, I am wondering how long it approximately takes to receive the luggage as this can vary greatly according to my experience.

Other information that may be important:
- I am a EU citizen
- London is just a layover (long connecting times. It's extremely unlikely that I would miss the flight)
- The flight will be operated by British Airways

Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116756/how-long-do-i-need-from-landing-to-reaching-the-train-station-in-z%c3%bcrich-airport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have absolutely no problems to catch your second option. I've done it in 10 minutes, so even taking into account the luggage and if you'll catch some queue at security (which at zrh is very efficient) you'll never have more than 1 hour to get to your train. 
Distances are short and there is only one gate where you'll have to take a train which takes around 5min.

Your information about the trains 10-15min every 10min is quite correct. You'll get the exact schedules at sbb.ch

Finally the bus station is 5mins (on foot) away from the train station, you'll have enough time there as well - just ask someone for directions.

Comment: I suppose you mean passport control, not security. The longest part is going to be waiting for check-in luggage, but that should still get you to the airport train station in waaaaay less than one hour.

Comment: Thank you both for your input! That was helpful!
Let's also hope that there won't be long lines to get a ticket for the train. Or do you buy it inside of the train?

Comment: You need to buy tickets before you board. You cannot buy tickets on board the train. There are ticket vending machines in the luggage hall. Where are you going? With a 18:20 arrival I would even expect to be able to take an 19:00 train...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am going to the central train station, and from there I want to take a bus to Germany.

Comment: For other people's information: I think it took me about 30 minutes from leaving the plane until being at the train station, which includes also picking up my luggage.